# Rails Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, authorization, roles

Hey, i need some help with rails, **again**! Last it was about Authlogic.. Well I'm gone a bit backward since.. I mean, Authlogic isn't a Authentcate system i like.. So now i wan't you guys to tell me what you think is the best!

I going to use it to a project of mine. Where there has to be a few roles like Admin, User and Guest.. So might you guys can tell me what is good and what is **bad**..?

Comment: You're mixing up authentication and authorization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split authentication from authorization.

Authentication covers the login/logout process. Authorization is directly linked to permission to see/use resources.

[Authlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) is a very good authentication gem.

For authorization you can check [CanCan](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan) from Ryan Bates, which is very simple to integrate with authlogic (just a single file in the models folder called ability.rb in which you configure all the app authorizations).

**EDIT:** You can also go with a simpler solution but you will lose flexibility

Answer (score 0):

I used Devise and it worked quite well, however it did not met my needs...
What you might need however looks like something super simple, something like this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/21-super-simple-authentication

Comment: @jpartogi I wanted to embed the login form as a partial and I could not do it. Also I would prefere having controllers generated in my source, so I could edit some details if I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I use Authlogic for authentication and DocSavage's Rails Authorisation plug-in for authorisation needs. Its a simple yet powerful plug-in.

Rails authorisation plug-in: http://github.com/DocSavage/rails-authorization-plugin